# How to get indexPath from table view?

Tags: iphone, sdk, path, indexing

So in my app, which is based around `UITableViews`, I am getting the `indexPath` for the row for methods like `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    // Extract Data

    CTCoreMessage *message = [[self allMessages] objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

My question is, what if I wanted to receive the `indexPath` in an `IBAction`? How would I do that since there is no `NSIndexPath` declaration in the header of the method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with this code, thank you to everyone that helped!

```
NSUInteger nSections = [self.messagesTable numberOfSections];
NSUInteger nRows = [self.messagesTable numberOfRowsInSection:nSections];
NSInteger lastSection = nSections - 1;
NSInteger lastRow = nRows - 1;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:lastSection];
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

But you don't really want the index path, you want the row, yes? You need to configure the sender (some `UIControl`) of the action to know your row.

Option 1: set the senders tag property (quick and simple).

Option 2: subclass the sender and add a property to store the row (technically correct).

Where you configure the sender depends on how and where you create it and how it relates to the table view, probably in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: So I could set the tag of the UITableView? Where and how?

Comment: The table view shouldn't be the sender you're talking about (if it is, you should be using one of the delegate methods which will already give you the index path). If your question is really: can I convert this delegate method to be an action? The answer is then just 'no'

Comment: Okay, so how could I use the tag method to accomplish this?

Comment: Which bit? What is wrong with the code you posted and why do you want to use an action? Do you have a button or did I just misinterpret your original question?

Comment: The button is on a row of the table view?

Comment: The button is not on the row, it is a delete button, so I'll need access to the exact row in question, CTCoreMessage.

Comment: How does the user know which message will be deleted when they tap the button?

Comment: The button is placed on a view displaying the message, that view is displayed when they tap on the cell. I on;y posted some of my didSelect.

Comment: Ok, so, when you show the message and add the delete button, that's where you set the buttons tag ( as indexPath.row), target and action. When the action is called, the button is passed as the sender. You can then get the tag and use it to delete the message.